# "John, he was" or "John was"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, difference, pronouns

I see some youtubers have a tendency to add pronouns where they are not required. For example they would say, "John, he liked fishing" instead of "John liked fishing".

Coffeehouse Crime is one particular youtuber who uses this structure.

Plenty of examples here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICxXHs5XF4Y

I'm curious about this. Is it the way English is used in the UK or maybe this is just particular to this youtuber. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you contact Coffeehouse Crime and ask them, rather than ask our opinion?

Comment: You must observe the context and situation where it is being used. He might be trying to make it a bit informal, though he has to put some extra effort to put words there even when not required.

Comment: Hi Brad,
I'm asking here because this is StackExchange and maybe someone has some ideas about why this is used like this. Maybe it's a personal quirk of this youtuber as I rarely come across this construction.

Thank you Mr Arslan for your comment. Maybe it's to make it more informal. I never thought of that. Maybe it's a type of prose then?